# Удаление объектов. Вопрос по теории

Tags: c++, qt

Изучаю вопрос о грамотном управлении памятью. Как я понял, вызывать метод `delete()` для каждого виджета необязательно, достаточно при его создании объявить ему `parent` и при удалении родителя будут удалены и все его дочерние виджеты.
Теперь, есть окно `QMdiSubWindow`. Код создания окна:

```
CatProducts *catProducts = new CatProducts();
catProducts->setObjectName("catProducts");
mdiArea->addSubWindow(catProducts);
catProducts->show();
```

Окну присвоен атрибут `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`. На это окно я вешаю `QWidget` как `internal widget`, а на него уже остальные виджеты. Код примерно такой:

```
QWidget *internalWidget = new QWidget(this);
setWidget(internalWidget);
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(internalWidget);
internalWidget->setLayout(layout);   

QTreeView *tree = new QTreeView;
tree->setFixedWidth(100);
layout->addWidget(tree,1, 1, 1, 3);
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("BUTTON");
layout->addWidget(button, 2, 1);
```

Теперь диспетчером задач в винде тестирую расход памяти открывая/закрывая моё `QMdiSubWindow`. При открытии объём потреблённой памяти увеличивается, а при закрытии не уменьшается. Т.е. занятая память не высвобождается. Как это нужно делать правильно?

**И ещё вопрос:** на примере `layout`'а, передача его в качестве параметра конструктора `QTreeView *tree = new QTreeView(layout)` и запись `layout->addWidget(tree)` идентичны? Т.е. в обоих случаях `layout` является родительским виджетом для `tree`?

Comment: Памяти много видов. Касательно оперативной (куча, которая LocalAlloc/VirtualAlloc) - она освобождается **всегда**. Какой из видов памяти вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Память которая не освобождается сама - это: разделяемая память, память USER-heap, память GDI-heap. Может я что-то упускаю, но всётаки уточните какую память вы теряете.

Comment: Тестировать надо не диспетчером винды, а специальными программами для поиска утечек. Поэтому пока нет какого-то существенного и постоянного увеличения расхода памяти при повторяющихся действиях, говорить об утечках преждевременно.

Comment: 1.Если вы не используете нетипичные обращения к памяти -то при закрытии программы она освободится полностью. Вероятность утечки почти 0.Утечка памяти-это когда после 1000-ного запуска система у вас будет не шевелится, тормозить, и писать вы исчерпали всю память-у вас 99,9%этого не будет. 2. Есть "локальная утечка" памяти во время работы то: Нормальная программа наестся памяти и всё. А если вы запрашиваете ещё ещё памяти и забываете, то ваша программа в диспечере будет больше и больше памяти показывать,аж пока не появится уведомление "вы исчерпали память",но после закрытия - память освободится.

Comment: @alexolut Вот, кстати, и ещё вопрос у меня, какие программы можно для этого использовать?

Comment: @nick_n_a Память, как я понимаю, куча. Я ж создаю виджеты через new. Но физически ведь и куча и стек - есть оперативная память компьютера?

Comment: [Тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows) посмотрите список.

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я как раз и хочу, чтобы моя программа не показывала "всё больше и больше". Как по-поводу второго моего вопроса из топика?

Comment: Тогда я отвечу так: если у вас нет желания осваивать всякие утилиты - создайте счётчик (переменная int), или процедуру счётчик. На каждый new увеличивайте счётчик, каждый delete уменьшайте. Можна один на всех, можно разные - на разные типы обьектов. Счётчики можно 1) посмотреть в дебагере. 2) сделать раздел - просмотр счётчиков. Так вы сможете проанализоровать поведение программы. Счётчики можно обвернуть в `#ifdef _debug` и `#endif` что б легче убрать было.

Comment: @nick_n_a Понял. Попробую. Спасибо.

Comment: @nick_n_a интересное описание reference counter... В плюсах же встроенный, нет?